# What does the identifier next to the dots mean?

Tags: toit

I just signed up for an account at toit.io, and in the console I have the term "dull-hour" written on the top right.

What does this stand for? Can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the company name that you signed up with, upon registration. Specifically, at this step:

[image: toit signup page]